# DAX Sum of children

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, tabular, dax

I'm working on a SSAS 2012 Tabular Model and am running into some difficulties with one of my measures.
What my setup looks like:

```
Dim Time hierarchy: Year - Season (Quarter) - Month

Fact Forecast: Account - Material - Month - Forecast Quantity - Bookings Quantity
```

I now need to calculate the Forecast accuracy but scoped to the period shown.
On a Month level, this is working by doing the following:

```
Forecast Accuracy:=1- (SUMX('Forecast',ABS(Forecast Quantity - Bookings Quantity))/Forecast Quantity)
```

My problem here starts on a higher grain, like Season or Year.
The biggest problem here is this part:

```
ABS(Forecast Quantity - Bookings Quantity)
```

Both quantities should first be aggregated to Account - Material -  level and then subtracted from eachother but I'm not able to get this to work.

Has anyone encountered this before because I don't have a clue how to solve this after crawling the web for half a day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05f5ad41-2f8d-47c8-a2f1-a33b97b97672/dax-sum-of-children?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel) By Gerhard Brueckl:

```
Forecast Error:=
    SUMX(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'Fact Forecast',
            'Fact Forecast'[Account],
            'Fact Forecast'[Material]),
        CALCULATE (
            ABS (
                SUM ( [Forecast Qty] ) - SUM ( [Bkgs Qty])
            )
        )
    )
```